# Resetting appengine-maven-plugin login credentials?

Tags: google-app-engine, appengine-maven-plugin

I have changed the account I want to use to do deployments.

**How do you change the login credentials once they are set?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This is hidden in the documentation page for the plugin:

> To solve this issue, change directories to `~`, locate a file named
> `.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java`, and rename it. Then try updating again.